# Follow/Unfollow button on mobile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I was following a tutorial(M. Hartl - railstutorial.org) on how to make a simple [follow/unfollow](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_rails_4/tree/master/app/views/relationships) [form](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_rails_4/tree/master/app/views/users) for users. When you click on 'follow', a relationship is created and you see 'unfollow' button. How can I do the same in mobile version of the app?

Comment: What aren't you getting, and how are you testing it?

Comment: I am simply using the button on mobile. When I click on follow button, relationship is created, but 'follow' button is not replaced by 'unfollow', like it is on desktop. Do you have the solution?